# Jenkins test fails with NoClassDefFoundError when shaded maven dependencies

Tags: maven, testing, jenkins, junit, dependencies

When Jenkins does execute automatically all junit tests for a java project with shaded dependencies inside the dependency hirarchy, it fails like

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/esotericsoftware/reflectasm/shaded/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1622)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:590)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.textFile(JavaSparkContext.scala:184)
        at com.bs.hdfs.conciliation.atm.SparkCheckDiffController.getSambaTraces(SparkCheckDiffController.java:127)
        at test.com.bs.hdfs.conciliation.atm.SparkCheckDiffControllerTest.testGetSambaTraces(SparkCheckDiffControllerTest.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 37 more
```

The not found class belongs to a shaded dependency. For instance, the above exception is thrown despite the dependency (reflectasm) being in the hierarchy:

[dependency hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL5lW.png)

Any solutions to avoid the test from failing?

Comment: Check java version, usually 'no class' exception have throwing if you use Java 9 by default.

Comment: In my case I just needed to put down the respective shaded jar in the classpath of the test. I am depending on photon-model-definition, the respective shaded jar for that is http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/org/jenkins-ci/lib/pipeline-model-json-shaded .